# Determining the entity that is consuming incresing amount of memory on 64-bit Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a Virtual Machine running 64-bit Windows 2008 Server R2. I have a bunch of processes running on it and we have noticed that the Memory Usage reported by the Performance Tab of the Windows Task Manager increases over time. In order to determine the process(es) that may be leaking memory, I ran a scheduled task every 5 minutes for 2 days that collects the Working Size for all the running processes. When I plotted the "Memory Usage reported by Performance Tab in Windows Task Manager", "Expected free memory=Total memory - sum of Working size for all processes" and the difference between these two, I see that the sum of the Working size for all processes is pretty flat i.e. no process appears to leak memory. However, the Memory Usage reported by Performance Tab in Windows Task Manager continues to increase steadily. When this memory usage reaches 8 GB (total memory), the machine crashes and has be rebooted manually. After the reboot, the memory usage starts from a low value and then again rises steadily.

Any ideas on how I can determine the "entity" that is using "increasing" amount of memory?